# How to enable a clear button action in UITextField (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm pretty new to Swift and I have a problem that I don't know how to solve. So, I have a `UITextField` where I have a limit of 5 characters max in the text field and I have no problems with stopping on fifth character, but the problem is that I can't clear text, because clear button probably consider to be a character in iOS.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, 
          shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, 
          replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

    if let count = textField.text?.characters.count {
        if count < 5 {
            print("\(count)")
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "...but the problem is that I can't clear text, because clear button probably consider to be a character in iOS"? What character?

Comment: when i have 5 characters in the text field and I want to remove (erase) the character I hit the < X | button that should delete the last character, but nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check what the length of the text field would be, not what it currently is. Try this:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, 
          shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, 
          replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

    let oldText: NSString = textField.text!
    let newText: NSString = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    let count = newText.length 
    if count <= 5 {
         print("\(count)")
         return true
    } else {
         return false
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not fluent in Swift. There may be a syntax error or two in this code.

Comment: your solution worked out for me with some changes, thanks

Comment: return newText.length <= 5

Answer (score 5):

You want to show the 'X' button to clear the text, right? Then use this:

```
textField.clearButtonMode = .WhileEditing
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking about.

Comment: Button is on the keyboard. Img of keyboard: http://bit.ly/1VhwFjL I don't want to delete the entire word, just the last character. Thanks for the answer.